# Drupal7: Trying to theme a specific page using a preprocess function, but...I get a blank screen instead

Tags: drupal, preprocessor, drupal-7

I've just discovered that if you want to alter a specific page (or group of pages) all you need is to add templates file to the core templates. For instance, I need to theme my /helloword page using a page--helloworld.tpl.php and node--helloworld.tpl.php template files.

Now all I get is a blank screen so I tried to write a preprocess function that adds support for custom theme files like:

```
<?php
/**
* Adding or modifying variables before page render.
*/
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  // Page change based on node->type
  // Add a new page-TYPE template to the list of templates used
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    // Add template naming suggestion. It should alway use doublehyphens in Drupal7.
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page--'. str_replace('_', '-', $vars['node']->type);   
  }
}
?>
```

I see no syntax error but I still get a blank screen. Still no luck

Is someone able to figure out what's wrong in the code/routine?

Drupal7 + Omega Sub-Theme

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a tiny bit of confusion here: a template file named `node--type.tpl.php` will automatically be called for any node which has the type `type`...you don't need to add the template suggestions in yourself.

There is one caveat to this, you have to copy the original `node.tpl.php` to your theme folder and clear your caches otherwise Drupal won't pick it up.

Also you don't want to use the `phptemplate_` prefix...rather you want your function to be called `MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page`.

Your code to add the page template based on the node type looks spot on, see if you still have the problem after you change your function name and clear the caches.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi @Clive, thanks a lot for the help. It works! The only thing it wonders me is that it works even WITHOUT the preprocess function. My theme is pomerania so I renamed as you said the function: pomerania_preprocess_page. One explanation is that maybe Omega theme has some advanced features and I inherit the functions already written. My theme is an Omega Starterkit theme. This is the reason I no longer can simple paste modules/node.tpl.php core templares and edit them because I use HTML5 syntax. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help :) I think you're right, it's probably some clever stuff that Omega does, a lot of these base themes do